# Update specific data from list rethinkdb ~python

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I have data structure like this in my rethinkdb:

```
{
    "id":"123",
    "otherId":"asd",                <== based on this
    "list": [
        {
            "id":"a",
            "list_id":"1",          <== and based on this
            "status":"available"    <== update this
        },
        {
            "id":"b",
            "list_id":"2",
            "status":"available"
        },
        {
            "id":"c",
            "list_id":"3",
            "status":"available"
        },
        {
            "id":"d",
            "list_id":"4",
            "status":"available"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to update status for list_id = 1, how do I do in python?

I tried to do it like this:

```
r.db('mydb').table('mytable').filter(r.row['Otherid'].eq("asd"))['list'].nth(0).default([]).filter(lambda doc: doc['list_id'] == "1").nth(0).default([]).update({"status":"offline"}).run()
```

But it gets me error `rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type SELECTION but found DATUM`

**UPDATE**

I can't query using id (primary key) because data is not given.

I also tried this way:

```
currentData = r.db('myDb').table('myTable') \
        .filter(r.row['otherId'].eq("asd"))['list'].nth(0).default([]) \
        .filter(lambda doc: doc['list_id'] == "1").run(con, time_format='raw')

currentData["status"] = "offline"

r.db('mydb').table('mytable').filter(r.row['otherId'].eq("asd"))['list'].nth(0).default([]) \
        .update(lambda row: row.merge({'list': row['list'].map(lambda row2: r.branch(row2['list_id'].eq("1"), currentData, row2))})) \
        .run(con, time_format='raw')
```

But it appends the new data instead of udpdate

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `map()` and `merge()`. Something like this:

```
r.table("mytable") \
 .filter(r.row['otherId'] == "asd") \
 .update({
     "list": r.row["list"].map(lambda item: item.merge(
         r.branch(item["list_id"] == "1", {"status": "offline"}, {})))
     })
```

I also suggest to use indices in your table and `get_all()` instead of `filter()`.

If `list_id` or `id` is always unique in the array under the `list` key, you could also just use an object (keyed by the unique id) instead of an array and make your life easier.